# Unit test for page reference

Tags: apex, unit-test, community, failing-tests

[image]

I had this pagereference method, My testmethod is

```
static  testMethod void testvalidate()     {
        String userid = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
        Map<String, String> QR = new Map<String, String>();
        String uid = UserInfo.getUserId();
        QR = Auth.SessionManagement.getQrCode();      
        String Secret = QR.get('secret'); 
        test.startTest(); 
        String status = 'test';
        String tokenInvalid = 'test';
        System.assertEquals(tokenInvalid,'test');
        System.assertEquals(status,'test');
        TwoFactorInfo TwoFactor = new TwoFactorInfo(UserId=uid , Type='TOTP', SharedKey=Secret );
        insert(TwoFactor);                    
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        AddTOTPcontroller  c = new AddTOTPcontroller();
        c.validate();
        System.assertEquals(null,c.validate());
        test.stopTest();
}
    }
```

Can i know why i get red lines even though i have needed test method. if i am wrong can any one help me correcting it?

Comment: As the `catch(Exception ex)` line is being covered it looks like your `validateTotpTokenForKey` method is throwing an exception. Examine the implementation and figure out what you need to setup in your test method to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

```
static  testMethod void testvalidate()     {
    String userid = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
    Map<String, String> QR = new Map<String, String>();
    String uid = UserInfo.getUserId();
    QR = Auth.SessionManagement.getQrCode();      
    String Secret = QR.get('secret'); 
    test.startTest(); 

    TwoFactorInfo TwoFactor = new TwoFactorInfo(UserId=uid , Type='TOTP', SharedKey=Secret );
    insert(TwoFactor);                    
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    AddTOTPcontroller  c = new AddTOTPcontroller();
   c.status = 'test';
   c.tokeninvalid = 'test';
   c.validate();
  System.assertEquals(tokenInvalid,'test');
  System.assertEquals(status,'test');
  System.assertEquals(null,c.validate());
  test.stopTest();
}
}
```